# object intitialization in method

Tags: php

Can I initiate an object instance and call a method  inside another method in php?

Please give me examples at this question.. and show me separately all the combinations that can be done with methods and objects.

```
class Autorizare{
    public  function user(){
        echo "This is a user";
    }
}

class Derivata{
    function derivata(){
        echo "sunt o derivata";
    }

    $object = new Autorizare();
    $object->user();

    $object2 = new Derivata();
    $object2->derivata();
}

echo $object->user();
echo $object2->derivata();
```

Something like this..

Comment: Just try it yourself and see what the possibilities are.

Comment: !!! Class is in class.. You can't define a class in another class.

Comment: is not in another class. it Throw me an error:  syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in C:\xampp\htdocs\series\ziua_13\exempluphp.php on line 8

Comment: you have to take out `$object = new Auto...` from the class definition.

Comment: Some good reads online: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access methods of some class in these ways:

```
  class A {     
        public function one() {
              echo "This is a user";
        }

        public static function two() {
              echo "This is not a user";
        }

        public function test() {
             $this->one();  //for non static methods
             self::two();   //for static methods
        }
  }

  class B {
        public function test1() {
             $a = new A();
             $a->one();  //for non static methods
        }

        public function test2() {
             A::two();  //for static methods
        }
  }

  $obj = new B();
  $obj->test1();
  $obj->test2();
```

For more details and also how to use scope look at [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)

*edit code upon comment request

Comment: i sow somewhere that initiate object and call method in class and i ask if is possible.

Comment: above i initiate object A in class B and called method one(). If you want to initiate object A in class A then you need to read about method [__construct()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php). If you want to access methods of A class IN A class then you call them like this: $this->one();

Comment: thanks! Can you show me all the combinations that can be done with methods and objects that you know?